# Ajax Form Submit Not Resetting or Firing Alert After Adding JQuery Validate Code

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I had this code working just fine before adding JQuery validation. Now, as it stands, the validation works fine, and once the submit button is pressed, I do get the email, but the last two statements (form reset and alert) no longer fire. WHat did I do wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#contact_form').validate({
        rules:{
        namefield:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 10
        },
        emailaddress:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 12,
        email: true
        },
        textmessage:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 12,
        maxlength: 2500
    },                  
},

        errorElement: "div",
        wrapper: "div class=\"validatemessage\""
     }),

        $('#contact_form').ajaxForm(function() {
        $('#contact_form')[0].reset(); 
        alert("Thank you for your email!");

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: look in browser console at errors. You have syntas issues with extra commas and at least one comma that should be semi-colon. JsHint is also helpful for validating js

Comment: ajaxForm options object is constructed incorrectly and should also be throwing errors. Look at docs for validation plugin and form plugin. They both have example integration code with each other. And use `success` callback in `ajaxForm`to run your alert and reset

Comment: Thank you very much for the JSHINT!! I corrected all the errors (except for "use strict, which Im nit sure about.) I still have the same issue.

Comment: here is the JsHinted code:

Answer (score 0):

```
            $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#contact_form').validate({
        rules:{
        namefield:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 10
        },
        emailaddress:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 12,
        email: true
        },
        textmessage:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 12,
        maxlength: 2500
    }                 
},

        errorElement: "div",
    wrapper: "div class=\"validatemessage\""
   });  

        $('#contact_form').ajaxForm(function() {
        $('#contact_form')[0].reset();
        alert("Thank you for your email!");

});
});
```

Comment: still need to properly integrate form and validat plugiins together. There are 2 ways to use them together. Docs for both plugins reference each other. Look for how `success` is coded in form plugin docs.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

You can reset your form in 2 ways:

**Method 1 : Use the** `resetForm()` **method**

```
$('#contact_form').ajaxForm(function() {
    alert("Thank you for your comment!")
    $('#contact_form').resetForm();
});
```

**Method 2 : Use the** `resetForm` **attribute in your form options**

> **resetForm** 
> Boolean flag indicating whether the form should be reset if
>   the submit is successful 
> Default value: *null*

Answer (score 0):

Move your `ajaxForm` call into the `submitHandler` function of the validate plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#contact_form").validate({
      rules:{
        namefield:{
        required: "Please enter your name",
        minlength: 10
        },
        emailaddress:{
        required:true,
        minlength: 12,
        email: true
        },
        textmessage:{
        required:"Your message is too short.",
        minlength: 12,
        maxlength: 2500

        }                 
    },

    errorElement: "div",
    wrapper: "div",  
    submitHandler:function(form){
      $(form).ajaxForm(function() {
        alert("Thank you for your comment!")
        form.reset();
      });
    }                    
  });
});
```